# Linking modal to a button

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid

https://www.fermento24.com  -  https://www.fermento24.com/collections/all

Site done with Shopify. Since on homepage it uses the standard material done by website, it is automatically linked to its modal ajax.

Meanwhile the collection page (second link) is generated by an app that figures filters and stuff. What I'd like to do is link the button to buy to this modal popup instead of bringing me in the cart page. I don't know how to go through this, is it a modification I should do in the modal or in the collection page template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the code listed below and might need some updates according to your theme.

**Need attention:** you need to check and create a way to update the mini cart after the product is added to the cart.

```
window.onload = function(){
   // disable the default behavior
   $('.boost-pfs-addtocart-btn').each(function(index, button){
     var $this = $(button);
     $this.closest('form').on('submit', function(e){ 
       e.preventDefault();
     });
   });
   // create new logic once the button clicked
   $(document).on('click', '.boost-pfs-addtocart-btn', function(){
     var form = $(this).closest('form');
     $.post('/cart/add.js', form.serialize(), function(data, status){
       if( status == 'success' ){
         // show popup once added to cart
         var model = $(".ajax-success-modal");
         model.fadeIn(500);
         var item    = form.parents('.boost-pfs-filter-product-item-inner')[0]
         var imgSrc  = $(item).find('.boost-pfs-filter-product-item-main-image').attr('src');
         var pTitle  = $(item).find('.boost-pfs-filter-product-item-title').text();
         var CPrice  = $(item).find('.boost-pfs-filter-product-item-regular-price').text();
         model.find(".ajax-product-image").attr("src", imgSrc);
         model.find(".added-to-wishlist").hide();
         model.find(".added-to-cart").show();
         model.find(".ajax-product-title").text(pTitle);
         model.find(".ajax_price").text(CPrice);
         model.find(".ajax_qty").text(1);
         // updating the cart counter in header
         $.get("/cart.js", function(data){
          $('#cartCount,.ajax_qtyA').text('').text(data.item_count);
          $('.ajax_cartTotal').text(Shopify.formatMoney(data.total_price, window.money_format));
         }, 'json');
       }
     }, 'json');
   });
}
```

please the code inside any JS file or just before the end of `</body>` and wrap it inside `<script></script>` tag if place it just before the body tag.

**Note:** Also make sure jQuery is the load before the code runs, otherwise the code failed, due to dependency over jQuery lib.

Comment: as you can see here: https://0101t4k1zrkoj5vd-26803830855.shopifypreview.com I've added the code at the end, before body, and I think the script is loaded after jQuery run(it should be right up in the head), but it doesn't seem to react to the new logic

Comment: sorry, there is a code typo error, update the answers, you need to copy and try again.